# Img srcset not changing images as per width given in html

Tags: html, responsive-design, pagespeed, srcset

I'm trying to display images based on the device. for e.g. Large Image for Desktop, Medium for Tablets, Small for Mobile and X-small for smaller mobile screens. I end up with following html for my images :

```
<img src="/media/1037/macbook.png" srcset="/LargeImage 900w,
                 /MediumImage 700w,
                 /SmallImage 400w,
                 /XSmallImage 300w" alt="" data-animate="fadeIn" class="aligncenter">
```

However when I keep my screen size 400 wide small image is not displayed and large image is displayed instead.Same for 300w screen size I get Medium image instead of x-small image.

Here is the link to check : [leadgeno.com](http://leadgeno.com)

On leadgeno.com, I'm trying to show images on section with "easy configuration option". I'll also attach screen shot of what section I'm trying to change images.

Please let me know, if I'm making any mistakes ?

[image]